# Why do I get errors abot undefined variables and errors with unserialize()?

Tags: commerce

Sometimes I get these errors on my site that I'm developing with the distribution of Commerce Kickstart:

> Notice: Undefined index: title_value en link_field_update_instance() (línea 1305 de /home/content/90/9397890/html/a/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/link/link.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: title_value en link_field_update_instance() (línea 1305 de /home/content/90/9397890/html/a/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/link/link.module).
>   Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 10301 of 11637 bytes en views_db_object->load_row() (línea 2243 de /home/content/90/9397890/html/a/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/includes/view.inc).

Do you have any suggestion about how to avoid these notices are reported?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the issue resolved would be to file an issue for the Commerce Kickstart project on drupal.org.

The reason you're receiving those notices is because ideally, in a perfect world, line 1305 would say something like this (to avoid such notices):

```
  if (function_exists('i18n_string_update') && isset($instance['widget']) && isset($instance['widget']['type']) && $instance['widget']['type'] == 'link_field' && isset($prior_instance['settings']) && isset($prior_instance['settings']['title_value']) && isset($instance['settings']) && isset($instance['settings']['title_value']) && $prior_instance['settings']['title_value'] != $instance['settings']['title_value']) {
```

But as you can probably see, that `if` statement is now twice as big. And since it's only a notice you're receiving, chances are the developer(s) won't put that issue as a top priority.

The easiest way to resolve the issue on your own though is to set the value of `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` inside your `php.ini` file, like so:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

That should suppress all notices that you might be seeing, including the third notice regarding `unserialize`.

Hope that helps... :)